# How to make Electron work with the most recent versions of jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, electron, bootstrap-5, popper.js

I am trying to make my Electron app work with the most recent versions of jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap. Unfortunately, neither referencing jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap nor "requiring" them in the `<head>` section of index.html (renderer process) does work.

I tried (option 1):

```
<script src='./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/cjs/popper.js'></script>
<script src='./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

And I tried (option 2):

```
<script>let $ = require('jquery');</script>
<script>require('popper.js');</script>
<script>require('bootstrap');</script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

Anyhow, I would like to maintain `nodeIntegration: false` if possible. Therefore, I prefer the first option (without `require`).

I get these errors (option 1):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined in "popper.js"
> ...

> index.html:85 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> ...

And I get there errors (option 2):

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'popper.js'
> ...

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).tooltip is not a function TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
> ...

> TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
> ...

These are the npm packages I am using:

```
@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2"
"bootstrap": "^5.0.0"
"electron": "^12.0.7"
"jquery": "^3.6.0"
```

**Is there any "best practice" way to include Bootstrap 5.0 (incl. the required "packages" jQuery and Popper) in my Electron app?**

PS: I have found many tutorials and hints on the Internet, but none of the approaches I have found seems to work with the most recent version of Bootstrap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set it up using:

`package.json`

```
"bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
"jquery": "^3.6.0"
```

and in `renderer.js`

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

Now everything seems to work properly

Answer (score -1):

You **cannot** refer to `node_modules` until you explicitly mention it. Moreover Explicit mentioning is a **Security Threat**

For Bootstrap 5 Just add:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For jQuery add:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You Just Copy their `CDN` File **as you usually do** when programming for a browser. It will work for Electron Too.

Comment: Requesting you to Accept the answer if it helps

Comment: One of the features of electron is that you can build standalone apps without the need of any internet connection. Using CDN would rely on online sources again.